# How to make a for loop wait for async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am making a request to predicthq API

```js
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  // [0] IS THE LONGITUDE 
  request.get("https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=Minnesota&limit=10", {
    headers
  }, (err, data) => {
    var results = JSON.parse(data.body).results;
    var serverRes = [];

    for (var i in results) {

      getGeo(results[i].location[1],   results[i].location[0]).then(v => {
        serverRes[i] = v;
      })
    } //end of for loop

    res.send(serverRes)

  }); // end of request call
}); //end of GET CALL

//ASYNC FUNCTIOON
function getGeo(lat, long) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    geocoder.reverse({
      lat: lat,
      lon: long
    }, function(err, res) {
      resolve(res)
    });
  });
}
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", () => {
        console.log("Button Clicked");
        $.get("/test",  function(data, status){
            console.log("data", data)
        });
    });//end of button clicked
});
```

to get a list of events. When I get the response I want to convert the lat, long of the response to an address and put it in an array variable. When I get the response from the server it gives me a list of empty arrays, How do I make the for loop wait until the geocoder.reverse gets the data, then move on to the other lat, long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that `for` loop to put those promises into an array, then use `Promise.all` to wait for them to resolve.

```
var results = JSON.parse(data.body).results;
var geoPromises = [];

for (var i in results) {
  var promise = getGeo(results[i].location[1],   results[i].location[0]);
  geoPromises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(geoPromises).then(vs => {
  res.send(vs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [async await](https://javascript.info/async-await)? Looking at it I think this could work for you.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("button").on("click", async () => {
    console.log("Button Clicked");
     await $.get("/test",  function(data, status){
        console.log("data", data)
    });
});//end of button clicked
```

});